# automatically opens microsoft store applications / games with python?

Tags: python

Hello guys I am developing a desktop assistant for myself with python. Is there a module that automatically opens microsoft store applications / games with python? If this is possible how to run it?

Comment: Asking for software/library recommendations is explicitly off-topic. Please see [help/on-topic], [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python can run anything the shell can via [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os#os.system). Find the target path of the shortcut to your application and then you can call `system()` on that string to open it with Python.

For example,

```
 os.system('calc.exe')
```

would open the Windows Calculator app.

> how can i find my app's names?

The shortcuts to them should be in the Start Menu folder. Double click on any folder (or use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) and paste

```
%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
```

into the Windows Explorer address bar, then find the shortcut to your app in there. You can use the shortcut in Python (use the full path: the file address and the name.lnk), or the target it's pointing to, which you can find with the "Properties" context menu item for the shortcut.

Comment: how can i find my app's names? for example I tried this for a microsoft game but it didn't work. but calc.exe is working.

Comment: you can use the crosshair of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer. Just drag it on the app and you get the path to the executable